# Download pdf instead of auto opening in the browser react js

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to download a pdf file using a link in react and when clicking on the link the pdf is opening in the browser instead of download.
I have enabled a setting in the browser to download the pdf and that works but is there any way where we can do in the code without manually changing the browser setting?

I have tried this,

```
<a style={{textDecoration : "none"}}download href={url}>YES</a>
```

but in this also i have to enable the setting manually in the browser.

It is working fine for all the other file types execpt pdf which is opening instead of downloading.

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask duplicate questions, there was nothing wrong with your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66541694/download-pdf-instead-of-auto-opening-in-the-browser-react-js#66541694).